# Error while installing with Python "pip": Cannot fetch index base URL http://

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install a local version of ScrumDo for testing. Only then I come to the point in my installation that I have to run:

> source bin/activate 
> pip install -r requirements.txt

I get the error:

> Downloading/unpacking django-storages
>
> > Cannot fetch index base URL http : //b.pypi.python.org/simple/
> > Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-storages
>
> No distributions at all found for django-storages
> Storing complete log in ./pip-log.txt

I googled a bit and search here and on Stack Overflow and found that I should add a --proxy= option and/or unset my http_proxy environment variable. Yet my install does not have a proxy and the environment var is not set. I tried running

> pip install -r requirements.txt --proxy=

Yet the error remains the same. I also created a /root/.pip/pip.conf containing:

> [global]
> index-url = http : //b.pypi.python.org/simple

and checked it the server actually was online and if the package django-storages existed, this was both true.

a last thing I tried, since the [install doc of ScrumDo](https://github.com/ScrumDoLLC/ScrumDo/wiki/Set-up) says so:

> pip install -U Django==1.1.4

yet again no succes... the error always remains the same, any one got any Ideas?

my pip-error.log shows the following (the URL works in firefox on a different machine in the same network that also uses no proxy):

```
/var/www/ScrumDo/pinax-env/bin/pip run on Mon Jul 30 10:24:08 2012
proxy):

Downloading/unpacking Django==1.1.4
proxy):

  Getting page http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django
proxy):

  Could not fetch URL http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
proxy):

  Will skip URL http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django when looking for download links for Django==1.1.4
proxy):

  Getting page http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/
proxy):

  Could not fetch URL http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
proxy):

  Will skip URL http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for Django==1.1.4
proxy):

  Cannot fetch index base URL http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/
proxy):

  URLs to search for versions for Django==1.1.4:
proxy):

  * http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django/1.1.4
proxy):

  * http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django/
proxy):

  Getting page http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django/1.1.4
proxy):

  Getting page http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django/
proxy):

  Could not fetch URL http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django/1.1.4: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
proxy):

  Will skip URL http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django/1.1.4 when looking for download links for Django==1.1.4
proxy):

  Could not fetch URL http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
proxy):

  Will skip URL http://b.pypi.python.org/simple/Django/ when looking for download links for Django==1.1.4
proxy):

  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django==1.1.4
No distributions at all found for Django==1.1.4
proxy):

Exception information:
proxy):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/ScrumDo/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 482, in main
proxy):

    self.run(options, args)
proxy):

  File "/var/www/ScrumDo/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 675, in run
proxy):

    requirement_set.install_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle)
proxy):

  File "/var/www/ScrumDo/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 2422, in install_files
proxy):

    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
proxy):

proxy):

  File "/var/www/ScrumDo/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 1485, in find_requirement
proxy):

proxy):

    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
proxy):


proxy):

DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for Django==1.1.4
```

Comment: i have already answered this question, please check the following the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327929/pip-cant-confirm-ssl-certificate/49958795#49958795

Answer (score 1):

Using following commands helped me. please try this

For upgrading pip
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip

For installing new packages, eg numpy, pandas etc.
python -m pip install PACKAGE NAME --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org

[upgrade pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJNMW.png)

[installing a package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo30M.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the exact same message, even from wget:

```
--2012-10-10 14:18:58--  http://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/
2012-10-10 14:18:58 ERROR 404: Not Found (Django does not have any releases).
```

That's very odd, the URL works fine on another computer, and wgetting the main page works fine.

EDIT: In my case, I had cached the IP in my /etc/hosts file for PyPI, and it was hitting that IP, which didn't work. After removing it and letting it use the normal DNS resolution procedure, it worked.